# Circular dependency reasonml

Tags: ocaml, reason, bucklescript

Let's say that I have a `1 -> n` relation: one todo can has many (or zero) notes and a note can have zero or one todo. How can I achieve this relation in ReasonML? (binding for an external lib)

Here is what I have come with at the moment (which is of course not working)

```
module Note = {
  module Attributes = {
    [@bs.deriving abstract]
    type t = {
      [@bs.optional]
      id: float,
      [@bs.optional]
      text: string,
      [@bs.optional]
      todo: Todo.Attributes.t,
    };
  };
};

module Todo = {
  [@bs.deriving abstract]
  type t = {
    [@bs.optional]
    id: float,
    [@bs.optional]
    title: string,
    [@bs.optional]
    completed: bool,
    [@bs.optional]
    notes: array(Note.Attributes.t),
  };
};

let todo = Todo.Attribute.t(~title="hello");
```

What if Note and Todo are in one file, an are in separated files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not familliar with Reason but in OCaml, one would do this kind of stuff using mutually recursive module, as in the following minimal example.

**Using mutally recursive requires to defines their module type:**

```
module type NoteSig = sig
  type t
end

module type TodoSig = sig
  type t
end
```

**and the actual modules:**

```
module rec Note : NoteSig = struct
  type t = {
      todo: Todo.t
    }
end

and Todo : TodoSig = struct
  type t = {
      notes: Note.t array
  }
end
```

If you prefer both module to be in a separate file, you can do pretty much the same thing using **functors** (still using the module signatures, let's say in a file *sig.ml*):

*a.ml:*

```
module Note (T:Sig.TodoSig) = struct
  type t = {
     todo: T.t
  }
end
```

*b.ml:*

```
module Todo (N:Sig.NoteSig) = struct
  type t = {
    notes: N.t array
  }
end
```

You can now instanciate your modules in an other file :

*c.ml:*

```
module rec NoteImpl = (A.Note(TodoImpl):NoteSig)
and TodoImpl = (B.Todo(NoteImpl):TodoSig)
```

I can only suppose there is a way to to do the same thing in Reason, probably by adding a lot of  brackets everywhere. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @ghilesZ. I tried your solution and it compiled fine but I cannot create an instance of Todo, please let me know what I did wrong https://gist.github.com/linktohack/7eb131c52f35af4e9429d7b3d17a59c3

Comment: Oh this is a different question. Here i think that you cant access the field "note" becose it does not appear in your signature. You can either make it appear in it, or add constructors/accessors to your module that allow you to manipulate your data without knowing your implementation. Anyway you should consider accepting the answer if it fixed your original problem.